# Scala for comprehensions performance compared

Tags: performance, scala, for-loop

Given two for comprehensions with identical semantics yet different declarations, to illustrate it consider

```
for ( i <- 1 to n ) yield { if (i % 2 == 0) 0 else 1 }
```

and

```
for { i <- 1 to n
      m = if (i % 2 == 0) 0 else 1 
    } yield m
```

which declaration proves more efficient, or else whether there is no significant performance difference despite the `if-else` expression declaration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they are the same exact thing both translate to:

```
(1 to n).map{i => if (i % 2 == 0) 0 else 1}
```

a **single** for-comprehension is just syntactic sugar for a **single** map

Comment: Wouldn't the second be translated to something like: `(1 to n).map{n => {val m = if (i % 2 == 0) 0 else 1; m}}`?

Comment: @Kigyo good point.  But I imagine the compiler would just inline m for you.  I might play around and look at the output of the compiler tomorrow